# SSIS Foreach loop adding extra date and extension to one file name

Tags: ssis

When my package runs the Foreach loop container to rename 4 excel files it adds the date to each files and then adds an extra date and extension to the 1 file in the folder.

Example: Contracts_010120.xlsx_010120.xlsx.

```
REPLACE( @[User::Copy_Temp_M_To_J] ,"_TEMP.xlsx", "")
     + "_"+Right("0"+ (DT_WSTR ,2) DATEPART("mm",GetDate()),2)  
     + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2)
     + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) ,2)
     + ".xlsx"
```

It's just doing it to one file in the folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that one of your files has already been transformed and does not have the _TEMP.xlsx in the name. Is it possible to check that your foreach wild card only processes files that end in _TEMP.xlsx?

Comment: SSIS questions tend to require screen shots of package internals to get meaningful answers. The formula by itself is fine. Something in the loop set up is your issue, but we can't see that.

Comment: Yes, all four files have _TEMP.xlsx. I watch the files get renamed. The Contracts_TEMP.xlsx gets renamed to Contracts_[Date].xlsx, then the other 3 files get renamed. Finally the Contracts_[Date].xlsx gets an renamed again with Contracts_[Date].xlsx_[Date].xlsx.

Comment: @EricBrandt I have added some pictures. I hope they will help.